# Rails - getting remote_user to return username from apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I've looked around quite a bit and did find some information on the topic but couldn't get it to work. I have apache/tomcat installed on my webserver within my company. Previously on the same webserver when I was writing CGI applications I was successfully able to get the username of visitors on my site by access the environment var REMOTE_USER. Now that I'm riding on rails, the variable, request.env['REMOTE_USER'] returns nothing.

Please note that I am not running Mongrel which many of the online discussions assume. Also, i'm not looking to build an authentication system, I'm just looking to read in (using REMOTE_USER) the username of the people who access my site.

I'm aware that I would need to tweak my .htaccess (located in my public folder) file to forward this information from apache into my application. By looking at examples on the web, I did change it to..

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=RU:%1]
RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-User %{RU}e
```

..but this didn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you add X-Forwarded-User, you have to read request.headers['X-Forwarded-User'] and not request.env['REMOTE_USER'].

Put this in the below file and use http_remote_user instead of the request.env hash.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def http_remote_user
    request.env['HTTP_REMOTE_USER'] || request.headers['X-Forwarded-User']
  end
  helper_method :http_remote_user
end
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back @squarsim. Pasted the code in my application controller, and in my view tried printing both, <%= http_remote_user %> and <%= request.headers['X-Forwarded-User'] %> ..still coming up with blank. Maybe I need to add/change something in my .htaccess?

Comment: Print out <%= request.headers %>  that's going to be the complete set of headers rails can work with, if you don't see it then there's something missing on the apache side.

Comment: Printed request.headers and got a page load of information. REMOTE_USER was missing from the output though. Does this mean i need to enable from Apache side?

Comment: If apache sees REMOTE_USER=bob and you don't see bob anywhere in request.headers then apache isn't forwarding anything and there's nothing rails can do about it.  So yes, I'd play with the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this, but did finally get it working.

1. Make sure you remember to add `RewriteEngine On` into the conf file (for me it was inside the `VirtualHost` section), I forgot and it silently failed, no errors when restarting apache.
2. Depending on whether you use a .htaccess or a .conf file, you need to change the the RewriteCond rule.  The [esoteric details - note 5](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) means we need to use `RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)` if we are inside a conf file.
3. To help debugging, you can always start by using `RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-User 'FixedValue'` to make sure the problems are apache not rails or other intermediates.